# Using multi text view one after the other macOSX

Tags: macos, swift

I dragged 3 multi label text and put them right above each other like this in the storyboard.

```
Multitextlabel1
Multitextlabel2
Multitextlabel2
```

But when i build the project there are a large number of spaces between them like this.

```
Multitextlabel1


Multitextlabel2



Multitextlabel3
```

How do i remove the spaces between the multi label texts in MACOSX.Any ideas?